# Django read file from model, [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

In Django I am using model forms to upload .stl file in model shown below. Once I submit form I see files get uploaded to myproject => media directory. But while reading uploaded file from the model, I am keep getting file not found error.
I tried using both absolute and relative path without success, any help is much appreciated.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class StlFile(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField()
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    volume = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import StlFile

class StlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StlFile
        fields = [
            'uploaded_file'
        ]
```

After POST request numpy stl reads saved stl file from the model in views.py.

**views.py**

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
from .forms import StlForm
from .models import StlFile
# Create your views here.
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StlForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            stl_file = form.save(commit=False) # Read file but Don't save the file yet
            stl_file.uploaded_file = request.FILES['uploaded_file'] # Read file instance in model parameter
            stl_file.save()
            # Extract mechanical properties from STL
            stl_path = stl_file.uploaded_file.url
            stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(stl_path) # Read saved file from the url
            volume, cog, inertia = stl_mesh.get_mass_properties()            
            return render(request, 'stl_upload/success.html')
    else:
        form = StlForm()
    return render(request, 'stl_upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

### Error

**Traceback Error**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/stl_upload/

Django Version: 3.1.1
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['stl_upload',
 'maths',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olahurikar\Desktop\Misllenious\MOD\Dango_Experiments\django_venv_experiment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\olahurikar\Desktop\Misllenious\MOD\Dango_Experiments\django_venv_experiment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\olahurikar\Desktop\Misllenious\MOD\Dango_Experiments\experiment\stl_upload\views.py", line 18, in model_form_upload
    stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(stl_path) # Read saved file from the url
  File "C:\Users\olahurikar\Desktop\Misllenious\MOD\Dango_Experiments\django_venv_experiment\lib\site-packages\stl\stl.py", line 328, in from_file
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:

Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /stl_upload/
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/media/panther_wH1qGon.stl'
```

Comment: Hi @Omkar, How does your `stl_upload/success.html` look like. I am working on similar kind project and your help would be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hi @NirajDPandey, Its working. I am interested to know more about your project. You can reach me at oalahuri@mtu.edu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, your media file could not be accessible. So we will use `MEDIA_ROOT` defined in your settings file. So:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
from .forms import StlForm
from .models import StlFile
from pacakge_name.settings import MEDIA_ROOT  # package_name , the folder inside which your settings.py is
# Create your views here.
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StlForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            stl_file = form.save(commit=False) # Read file but Don't save the file yet
            stl_file.uploaded_file = request.FILES['uploaded_file'] # Read file instance in model parameter
            stl_file.save()
            # Extract mechanical properties from STL
            stl_path = f"{MEDIA_ROOT}/{Stl_file.uploaded_file.name}"
            stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(stl_path) # Read saved file from the url
            volume, cog, inertia = stl_mesh.get_mass_properties()            
            return render(request, 'stl_upload/success.html')
    else:
        form = StlForm()
    return render(request, 'stl_upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
```